# Ruby coin toss probability tool

Tags: ruby

I haven't been programming for a while, I wanted to do a simple project to warm myself up and get back into the game; I made this simple tool that finds the probabilities of coin toss combinations. Enter a number to get all combinations with that many flips, or enter a string to search for that combination, i.e. `H**H` would find all combinations starting and ending with heads.

```rb
module Every
  def every(&block)
    arys = map do |ary|
      base_ary = eval ary.inspect.split(':')[1] rescue nil
      base_ary.nil? ? ary : base_ary
    end
    longest = arys.max_by(&:count).count

    arys.map!.with_index do |ary, i|
      cyc = ary * ( longest / ary.count + 1 )
      self[i].is_a?(Enumerator) ? cyc[0...longest] : ary
    end
    arys.transpose.each &block
  end
end

class Array
  # I didn't have to use this module, but I had written it in the past 
  # and this seemed like a good place to use it
  include Every
end

class CoinToss
  attr_accessor :outcomes, :reference, :iterations, :combins, :occrs

  def initialize(outcomes = ["H", "T"], reference = gets.chomp.upcase)
    @outcomes = outcomes.each &:to_s
    if (Integer reference rescue false)
      @iterations = reference.to_i
      @reference = "*" * @iterations
    else
      set = @outcomes.join("*")
      raise ArgumentError, "Invalid Characters" unless reference =~ /\A[#{set}]+\z/
      @reference = reference
      @iterations = @reference.length
    end

    @combins = @outcomes.repeated_permutation(@iterations).to_a
    @occrs = 0

    ref = [@reference.chars]
    # every loop ref is repeated but combins is iterated
    [ref.cycle, @combins].every do |r, c|
      # replaces `*` in ref with regex string for characters from `outcomes`
      @template = r.join.gsub "*", "[#{@outcomes.join}]"
      @occrs += 1 unless !(c.join =~ /#{@template}/) # +1 if it matches the template
    end
  end

  def get_combins(match_marker = "~")
    @combins.each do |c|
      # m is blank if combin doesn't match the template
      m = !(c.join =~ /#{@template}/) ? "" : match_marker
      line = Array c.join
      # skips marker when reference contains only `*`
      line << m unless @reference.chars.all? { |r| r == "*" }
      puts line.join(" ")
    end
  end

  def get_probability(rationalize = true, match_word = "out of")
    puts Rational(occrs, combins.length) if rationalize
    puts [@occrs, match_word, @combins.length].join(" ") unless rationalize
  end
end


tosses = CoinToss.new
tosses.get_combins
tosses.get_probability(rationalize = false)
tosses.get_probability(rationalize = true)
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions to your code

### Every module

I had quite a hard time to understand what it does.

Using eval can be quite dangerous so I would try to avoid it.

```rb
eval ary.inspect.split(':')[1] rescue nil
```

You used a module to monkey patch the Array class which is sensible. Another, even more safe way to monkey patch could be to use refinements.

> Refinements are designed to reduce the impact of monkey patching on other users of the monkey-patched class. Refinements provide a way to extend a class locally.

https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html

The safest way of course is to not use monkey patching at all. Maybe something like `array.flatten.each` could do the trick too?

### CoinToss

#### Initialize reference

Initializing the reference in your constructor looks quite complicated. Maybe it could get extracted to dedicated classes.

```rb
class Reference
  def initialize(input, allowed_characters = [])
    @input = input
    @allowed_characters = allowed_characters
  end

  def to_s
    if integer?
      IntegerReference.new(input.to_i)
    else
      StringReference.new(input, allowed_characters)
    end
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :input, :allowed_characters

  def integer?
    Integer(reference)
  rescue
    false
  end
end

class IntegerReference
  def initialize(size)
    @size = size
  end

  def to_s
    build_string
  end

  def valid?
    true
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :size

  def build_string
    "*" * size
  end
end

class StringReference
  def initialize(string, allowed_characters = [])
    @string = string
    @allowed_characters = allowed_characters
  end

  def to_s
    return string if valid?
  end

  def valid?
    string =~ /\A[#{validation_regex}]+\z/
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :string

  def validation_regex
    allowed_characters.join("*")
  end
end
```

## Use getter

You already setup attribute accessors but then fail to use them. Instead of `@combins` use `combins`. This has the advantage that you can change the way `combins` is returned by changing the getter method.

### Return data instead of puts

Return data from your methods instead of using a puts. This has several advantages likes

- Use the classes outside a terminal (e.g. website)
- Easier to test

### Naming

There are only two hard things in computer science ... Try to use speaking names and avoid abbreviations like `combins`, `occrs`, `r`, `c`. This will help to make your program easier to read and understand.

### Lazy loading

Instead of setting up everything in the controller, use lazy loading and memoization.

```rb
def combinations
  @combinations ||= outcomes.repeated_permutation(@iterations).to_a
end

def iterations
  @iterations ||= reference.length
end
```